# PHP - Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, email, memory

I have the following code:

```
<?php 
namespace Debug;

function Alert($msg){
   $temp = "<script>alert('".$msg."')</script>";
   echo $temp;
}

function Log($msg){
   $temp = "<script>console.log('".$msg."')</script>";
   echo $temp;
}

function Mail($message, $subject){
   $to = "email@email.com";

   // Sending email
   if(mail($to, $subject, $message)){
       echo 'Your feedback has been sent successfully.';
   } else{
       echo 'Unable to send feedback. Please try again.';
   }
}

?>
```

Different file:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['feedback_name'];
    $email = $_POST['feedback_email'];
    $msg = $_POST['feedback_message'];

    echo $name;
    echo $email;
    echo $msg;

    include 'WebLib.php';

    Debug\Mail($msg, "Feedback");
?>
```

Since I wrote the Mail() function i get this error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the guess it is going into an infinite loop. Update `mail($to, $subject, $message)` to `\mail($to, $subject, $message)` and try, since you are namespacing. In PHP function names are case insensitive. `\mail(...)` will call the global PHP function.